# Testing Spring controllers by (pseudo) directly calling that handler method - good or bad? how to implement it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, testing

In one sentence: *I want the `MockMvc` perform as if I am **directly calling the controller***.

<sup>(P.S. That is syntax sugar. It does not mean *I am really calling controllers when integration test*.)</sup>

---

Details:

Say we have a Restful controller:

```java
class BookController {
    public Book updateBook(int id, Book newBook) {...}
}
```

A typical [Spring integration testing](https://www.baeldung.com/integration-testing-a-rest-api) for a RESTful service looks like:

```java
mockMvc.perform(put("/books/1")
                .content("{\"id\":1, \"name\": \"ABC\", ...}")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is("ABC")))
                ...and more...;
```

However, can we do things like:

```java
BookController magicBookController = SomeMagic.generate_the_magic_controller();
Book result = magicMvc.perform(magicBookController.updateBook(1, new Book("ABC", ...)));
assertThat(1, result.getId());
assertThat("ABC", result.getName());
...
```

**EDIT**: The code above is *not* simply calling the `new BookController().updateBook(...)` method! What I hope is: The `generate_the_magic_controller` will generate dynamic proxies (using cglib). Then, when we call `magicBookController.updateBook`, actually the dynamically generated code looks like:

```
Book dynamically_generated_updateBook(int id, Book book) {
    String url = magic_assemble_url(id); // will become: "/books/1"
    String content = magic_assemble_content(book); // will become: "{name: AAA, ...}"
    Something result = mockMvc.perform(put(url)
                .content(content)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    return parse_result(result); //parse back into book
}
```

---

In one sentence: *I want the `MockMvc` perform as if I am **directly calling the controller***. My question:

1. Shall I do it? (Or this is a very bad practice?)
2. How to do it? I am thinking to hack the part in Spring framework about "finding and parsing controllers", but do not have concrete ideas about how to do that...

**EDIT**: My goal of testing is as follows. Originally people liked to test code by their eyes (give inputs and look at outputs and assert by their mind). Of course, that is bad. So we write down things like "post to /books and assertThat the outcomes are correct". That is what I want to test. It is actually a bit like E2E test (since this is a restful service) IMHO. (Or is my goal wrong completely?)

---

**EDIT**: A typical test in Jersey, which I think (personally) is more elegant than Spring tests:

```java
Profile profile = resources.getJerseyTest()
                              .target("/v1/profile/" + AuthHelper.VALID_NUMBER_TWO)
                              .request()
                              .header("Authorization", AuthHelper.getAuthHeader(AuthHelper.VALID_NUMBER, AuthHelper.VALID_PASSWORD))
                              .get(Profile.class);
assertEquals(profile.getXXX(), "aaa");
...
```

Thanks very much for any ideas!

Comment: Calling the controller method directly would be appropriate in a unit test, not an integration test.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It is not simply calling the controller method. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of `MockMvc` is to test the REST API are configured correctly using the spring-mvc infrastructure such as things likes an HTTP request can be mapped to and invoke an expected controller method with the correct parameters , the java object returned from the controller method can be serialzied to the correct JSON body in the HTTP response etc. It is about testing if the REST API behave correctly given a HTTP request, so your must specify an HTTP request if you want to use `MockMvc`

It seems to me that you want to test your rest client such as things like it can send the request to the expected URL with the expected body , and it can deserialise the JSON response back to the java object etc. rather than testing if your REST API is configured properly. If yes , you can stub the REST API using the tools like `Wiremock` or `okhttp MockWebServer`, and use the rest client as usual to call the stubbed API.

So , the first thing to ask yourself is that what thing do you want to test actually ? Normally we only focus on testing one thing in each time. And it is better to specify the test inputs directly and declaratively without any complex code conversions involved such as convert some given input to the input that are really needed by the test as more conversion codes means more chances to introduce another aspect of error.

So if you want to test if you configure the spring-mvc API correctly (i.e using mockMvc) , it is a bad idea to implement something that translate your generated rest client to the HTTP request that are actually needed to invoke the API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! (1) I want to do integration tests, which IMHO is like: Originally people liked to test code by their eyes (give inputs and look at outputs and assert by their mind). Of course, that is bad. So we write down things like "post to /books and `assertThat` the outcomes are correct". That is what I want to test. It is actually a bit like E2E test (since this is a restful service) IMHO. (2) I am confident about "url to controller mapping", "response object to json string", etc (since the client is Swagger-generated). [to be continued]

Comment: (continued) In addition, I do not need to test any REST client. Neither do I need testing "json -> object", "url -> body" etc. I am also not aim at "configuring spring-mvc API correctly". (3) In short, I want to do an integration / e2e test. And I do not like the current `MockMvc` that I have to care about the urls, the input strings (instead of objects), etc... Thanks very much!

Comment: I edited the question, adding the "Jersey test" part :)

Comment: if you want to do e2e test that must start from the generated rest client , then mockMvc is not designed for this purpose  which its design is more unit test focus. Alternatively , if you want to have the similar experience compared to Jersey , you can take a look on `TestRestTemplate` together with `@SpringBootTest` , but they are still not for e2e test that you are looking for

Comment: @KenChen Thanks very much! Please ignore my words about Swagger code generator if it confuses you. I am thinking about an "e2e test where the 'e' means REST apis" (is this idea itself wrong?), so I do not think I need to use the generated rest client (in Flutter language...). So with this information, do you suggest TestRestTemplate, MockMvc, or something else?

Comment: @KenChen In addition, where do you get the knowledge that "mockmvc is more for unit test than integration / e2e tests"? I hope I can learn it (from some books?) since I am completely a newbie now... Thanks!

Comment: So ignoring those rest client , do you want  to test a correct HTTP response is received given a HTTP request ? If yes , I would stick to mockMvc , mock the dependencies required by the rest controller , and verify the received HTTP response .

Comment: Er it seems that the "mock dependencies requried by controller (should be Service right?)", is a *unit test* on the *controller* layer (do I understand correctly?). But I want some *integration/e2e* test... Thanks!

Comment: because when talking about e2e test , we normally tend to test the real stuff which involve really start a server , the request really go through the network etc. But in case of mockMvc, it does not require really start a server and require network , it just run in memory . Although some may argue that it is a kind of integration test as it requires to start the spring application context, my point is that it is must not be the type of e2e test

Comment: Thanks very much! But I wonder what is the *benefit* of the "really start server and go through real network", compared with "mockmvc test with almost no mocking"? I think the former will need more time and the environment is more possible to break, while it does not test more business logic...

Comment: Though I do not fully understand, still give you an "accept" :)